# Doesn't take the result from View to ViewModel MVVM light

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light

My ViewModel Doesn't take the value from model

I create the model

```
public class UserModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string firstName;


    public string Firstname
    {
        get => firstName;
        set
        {
            firstName = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Firstname");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

my view model

```
UserModel user = new UserModel();
public UserModel User
{
    get => user;
    set => Set(ref user, value);
}
```

and in model I bind with this line `User.FirstName`

```
<TextBox x:Name="FirstName" Style="{StaticResource FirstNameBox}" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" >
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding  Mode="TwoWay" Path="User.FirstName" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <DataErrorValidationRule ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="False"/>
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
```

but I take null. take example frome this answer [mvvm calculated fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14237180/mvvm-calculated-fields)

Comment: Do you have PropertyChanged event inside the FirstName property block?

Comment: `NotifyPropertyChanged("Firstname");` in model, FirstName set

Comment: I think propertyChanged event must also be called on User in viewmodel, not only in properties of usermodel

Comment: I'm asking about event handler. Your model class isn't correct. You cannot have event declaration inside a property block. And implement INotifyPropertyChanged to your ViewModel properties too.

Comment: set => Set(ref user, value);  have same meaning  in vm, i try like you say , null value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The binding paths are case-sensitive. You should bind to User.First**n**ame or change the name of the property to First**N**ame:

```
public string FirstName
{
    get => firstName;
    set
    {
        firstName = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Firstname");
    }
}
```